# Javascript replace with regular expression - Replace only part of string found

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like the following:

*"01/11/2012 (Last, First) - Notes,02/11/2012 (Last, First) - More Notes,03/11/2012 (Last, First) - Even More Notes,09/12/2012 (Last, First) - You get the idea"*

I would like each note to fall on a new line by replacing any comma followed by a number with '\n'.

I have tried `.replace(/,/g, '\n')` but I get a newline in the middle of the name.
So I do `.replace(/,\d/g, '\n')`, however then I loose the first number of the date.

How can I search for ,# and replace it with \n# where the number is the same as it was previously?

I want the result to look like this:

```
01/11/2012 (Last, First) - Notes
02/11/2012 (Last, First) - More Notes
03/11/2012 (Last, First) - Even More Notes
09/12/2012 (Last, First) - You get the idea
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture to avoid missing that number:

```
s.replace(/,(\d)/g, '\n$1')
```

Comment: Thanks, I had done this in the past, I just was having trouble finding the syntax anywhere.  Monday morning Google skill need some work :)

Comment: No problem :). All Monday mornings always need some tuning of ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

(**Update**, sorry, just noticed that you don't want the comma)

Try...

```
.replace(/,(\d)/g, '\n$1')
```

This groups the `\d` and then uses it (with `$1`) in the replace